# UIGraphics memory leaks

Tags: ios, objective-c, uigraphicscontext

```
- (UIImage *)deleteBackgroundOfImage:(UIImageView *)image
{
    CGRect rect = CGRectZero;
    rect.size = image.image.size;

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.size, YES, 0.0);

    UIImage *mask = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.size, NO, 0.0);

    {
        CGContextClipToMask(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), rect, mask.CGImage);
        [image.image drawAtPoint:CGPointZero];
    }

    UIImage *maskedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return maskedImage;
}
```

when I call the above function for twice,I got "Received memory warning",anybody can tell me where leaks .thank in advance.

Comment: Do you mean that a memory warning reliably comes out when you repeatedly call this function?  There is nothing wrong here so I think the problem is actually somewhere else.  Unless the image is ridiculously huge.

Comment: I have tried many times,when I don't call this function ,everything is ok

Comment: What are you *doing* with these images once you make them?

Comment: in order to make the code simple,I comment it